# Netbeans java applet codebase relative path

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, relative-path

I have this directory structure:

[image]

and I have this code (from the book I am reading)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Saluton Mondo!</title>        
    </head>
    <body 
        bgcolor = "#000000" 
        text = "#FF00FF" >

        <p> This is a Java applet.</p>

    <applet
        code ="SalutonApplet.class"
        codebase="..\\..\\build\\classes"
        height="150"
        width="300"
        >
        <p>You need a Java-enabled browser to see this.</p>
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

and of course java class  - not really relevant for this question, but anyway:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class SalutonApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    String greeting;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        greeting = "Saluton mondo!";
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics screen) {
        Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
        screen2D.drawString(greeting, 25, 50);
    }
}
```

and if I point and click on that HTML file with Windows Explorer, it opens default browser and applet is displayed correctly:

[image]

However, I want to open it through Netbeans directly, with Right Click-> View option, and I struggle to figure out what would be the relative path in Netbeans do do this? I already tried several different options but it won't work. Of course if I put absolute path such as codebase="C:\Users\Nenad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\build\classes" then it works, but I want to do it with relative path.

Project structure in Netbeans look like this:

[image]

So I found what the problem was:

It should be

```
codebase="..\\build\\classes"
```

instead of

```
codebase="..\\..\\build\\classes"
```

**Then to my surprise, if I move those SalutonApplet.html & SalutonApplet.java into day17 package,**

[image]

and to reflect that change I update codebase accordingly to

```
codebase="..\\..\\build\\classes\\day17"
```

but again I have the same problem? I don't get it why? I added two levels up (from day17, and src it should go to Java24)

```
c:\Users\Nenad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\src\day17\
```

should become

```
c:\Users\Nenad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24
```

and then

```
C:\Users\Nenad\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\build\classes\day17
```

**should bring it right where it should be - but obviously not, why?**

And one more question - if I try to use embedded WebKit browser it gives me error "You need a Java-enabled browser to see this" - is there option to enable this or that browser has no capability of being Java enabled browser?

Comment: Before I started using Maven, I usually did something like this when I was confused about paths: Write a small application in Netbeans which creates a file called "test.txt", and afterwards search through the file system where it has ended up. That way you know your default 'root' path from Netbeans :-)

Comment: I will do that next time - I really have no much experience with NetBeans, mostly I do my projects in Eclipse. Thanks for the tip!